# Django How To Add Number From Other Object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can i add an int value inside of a field in multiple object to be displayed in another object. Lets say that i need to add all of the item that the customer have ordered previously and store them inside of all_previous_orders.

For example if customer no 1 making an order for 10 fruits and then later making another order for 1 car then the field inside of customer object named "all_previous_orders" will add all of the number of item inside of order object (10 fruits + 1 car = 11 item).

### Result.json

```
[
    {
        "customer_name": "John Doe",
        "order": [
            {
                "order_name": "fruit",
                "how_many_order": 10,
            },
            {
                "order_name": "car",
                "how_many_order": 1,
            },
        ],
        "all_previous_orders": 11
    },
]
```

### Models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    how_many_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

### Serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change your `CustomerSerializer` a bit to add a `count` for the past orders:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    all_previous_orders= serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    orders = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'orders', 'all_previous_orders')
    
    def get_all_previous_orders(self, customer):
        count = Order.objects.filter(customer=customer).count()
        return count
```

Comment: Also missing related_name parameter on the model to obtain expected result. `customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')`

Comment: Hello haduki, it seems i didnt specify enough on the problem. What i actually need is to add all of the value of how_many_order field instead of counting how many order object that the customer have. Do you know how to modify the code to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: you mean you want to specify each different order into your json?

Comment: no, what i mean is if we look at result.json for every order that the customer make it's going to have how_many_order in integer. now what i need is to add all of the value inside of every order object that the customer have and put it into all_previous_orders.